# ASP.NET custom controls - custom property doesn't hold the assigned value on postaback

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, c#-2.0

I have a custom asp-net control that inherits from another one and its works as expected, though the properties are only set properly if i code them in the markup directly, so for instance if i need set a property at runtime that is some dynamic value, this value is never set or somehow lost.

Here's the markup code:

```
<!--related form-->
<fw:advancedformdisplay id="formDisp" runat="server" captchaenabled="true" EmailEnabled="true" EnableViewState="true" captchaprivatekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" captchapublickey="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" captchatheme="white" SourceType="MenuItem" SourceMainId="Auto">
</fw:advancedformdisplay>
```

This is the code of the control:

```
    [DefaultProperty("CaptchaEnabled"),ToolboxData("<{0}:AdvancedFormDisplay runat=server></{0}:AdvancedFormDisplay>"), Description("This is an enhanced FormDisplay control that inlcudes Googles Captcha control is enabled")]
public class AdvancedFormDisplay :SiteBuilder.WebControls.FormDisplay
{
    bool _CaptchaEnabled = false, sendEmail = false;
    string captchaErrorMessage = "The verification code entered is not valid. Please try again!";
    RecaptchaControl captchaControl = null;
    string captchaPrivateKey = "", captchaPublicKey = "", captchaTheme = "clean";
    string originalFormHtml = string.Empty;
    string afterText = string.Empty, beforeText = string.Empty;
    Literal litHtmlForm = null;
    string captchaErrorClass = "errorCaptcha";

    public string EmailBeforeText
    {
        get { return beforeText; }
        set { beforeText = value; }
    }

    public string EmailAfterText
    {
        get { return afterText; }
        set { afterText = value; }
    }

    public string CaptchaErrorClass
    {
        get { return captchaErrorClass; }
        set { captchaErrorClass = value; }
    }

    public bool CaptchaEnabled
    {
        get { return _CaptchaEnabled; }
        set { _CaptchaEnabled = value; }
    }

    public bool EmailEnabled
    {
        get { return sendEmail; }
        set { sendEmail = value; }
    }

    public string CaptchaErrorMessage
    {
        get { return captchaErrorMessage; }
        set { captchaErrorMessage = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// red,white,blackglass,clean
    /// </summary>
    public string CaptchaTheme
    {
        get { return captchaTheme; }
        set { captchaTheme = value; }
    }

    public string CaptchaPrivateKey
    {
        get { return captchaPrivateKey; }
        set { captchaPrivateKey = value; }
    }

    public string CaptchaPublicKey
    {
        get { return captchaPublicKey; }
        set { captchaPublicKey = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }


    public override void OnSaved(FormDisplayEventArgs e)
    {
        //If captcha control is enabled we need to adda  bit of code to redirect form properly
        if (CaptchaEnabled && e.Redirect && !e.SendMail)
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }

        if(sendEmail)
        {
            //Send email
        }

        base.OnSaved(e);
    }

    public override void OnSaving(FormDisplayEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CaptchaEnabled)
        {
            //Validate and do stuff
        }

        base.OnSaving(e);
    }
}
```

And then in my asp.net page that is using control, created by markup code, in the Page_Load() i try to assign some values to some properties and and the values aren't set properly, meaning that if i have set for isntance, the property EmailBeforeText = "somthing" this value will not be assigned..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //2: Get the language of menuitem - Based on current culture setting (for by dropdownbox - change logic)
    try
    {
        currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();

        // Redirect if domain does not match rootnode.
        DomainChecker.CheckURL(this.Request, this.Response, currentCulture);

        if (footerArticle != null)
            footerArticle.SourceMenuId = Digimaker.Config.Custom.Get("FooterID_" + currentCulture).ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        currentCulture = "en-GB";

        if( footerArticle != null )
            footerArticle.SourceMenuId = Digimaker.Config.Custom.Get("FooterID_" + currentCulture).ToString();
    }
```

Any ideas what i'm missing here?

Thanks a lot for your reading!

Regards,
byte_slave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: use viewstate to persist your custom values!

- [Understanding ASP.NET ViewState whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) (see example with `NavigateUrl`)

edit: as reading the white-paper is obviously a really hard thing:

> Each control is responsible for storing its own state, which is
>   accomplished by adding its changed state to its ViewState property.
>   The ViewState property is defined in the System.Web.UI.Control class,
>   meaning that all ASP.NET server controls have this property available.
>   (When talking about view state in general I'll use lower case letters
>   with a space between view and state; when discussing the ViewState
>   property, I'll use the correct casing and code-formatted text.)
>
> If you examine the simple properties of any ASP.NET server control
>   you'll see that the properties read and write directly to the view
>   state. (You can view the decompiled source code for a .NET assembly by
>   using a tool like Reflector.) For example, consider the HyperLink Web
>   control's NavigateUrl property. The code for this property looks like
>   so:

```
public string NavigateUrl
{
  get
  {
    string text = (string) ViewState["NavigateUrl"];
    if (text != null)
       return text;
    else
       return string.Empty;
  }
  set
  {
    ViewState["NavigateUrl"] = value;
  }
}
```

> As this code sample illustrates, whenever a control's property is
>   read, the control's ViewState is consulted. If there is not an entry
>   in the ViewState, then the default value for the property is returned.
>   When the property is assigned, the assigned value is written directly
>   to the ViewState.

Comment: I tried to EnableViewState = true, but didn't work. Or do you mean, setting the viewstate manually like Viewstate["MycustomVar"] = "foo" ?

Comment: you need to persist the value to the viewstate (your field/property is a different thing as the viewstate) - just read the white-paper and/or the example (in this white-paper) for `NavigateUrl`

Comment: @byte the second. Instead of using a private variable to back your properties, have your getter and setter interact with ViewState["something"]